# Passing onclick event to inherited class using react / typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface

I am following the Facebook react tutorial using Typescript. However its my first time with react and typescript. I want to pass an onClick event to the 'Square' class which using typescript implements a state and props interface.

How do I enable this Square class to accept my onClick event and fire it as expected? Struggling with the syntax sugar atm.

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface MyProps {
    value?: string;
}

interface MyState {
    value?: string;
    squares?: any[];
}

class Square extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            value: null,
            squares: [null]
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.setState({ value: 'X' })}>
                {this.state.value}
            </button>
        );
    }
}

class Board extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            squares: Array(9).fill(null),
        };
    }
    renderSquare(i) {
        return <Square value={this.state.squares[i]} onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)} />;
    }
    render() {
        const status = 'Next player: X';
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="status">{status}</div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(0)}
                    {this.renderSquare(1)}
                    {this.renderSquare(2)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(3)}
                    {this.renderSquare(4)}
                    {this.renderSquare(5)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(6)}
                    {this.renderSquare(7)}
                    {this.renderSquare(8)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Game extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="game">
                <div className="game-board">
                    <Board />
                </div>
                <div className="game-info">
                    <div>{/* status */}</div>
                    <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// ========================================

export class ReactTut extends React.Component<any, void> {
    public render() {
        return <Game />
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed to add an optional function to the MyProps interface.
`interface MyProps {
    value?: string;
    onClick?(): void;
}`

Answer (score 1):

I was following a similar tutorial about tic-tac-toe, here is my solution for your reference:

```
onClick: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
```

Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just make the "onClick" property typesafe as below:

```js
interface MyProps { 
    value?: string, 
    onClick?
}
```

This will give onClick a type of "any", then you can pass in any function you like. If you know you would pass in a certain type of function, then you can try to create a generic function type and set it to onClick.